# Dynamically update the UI when selecting a date

Tags: ajax, jsp, dynamic, jstl

I'm trying to learn some basic knowledge of jsp, suppose that I have a project, in this project, after signing in, I have a Main.jsp with a calendar or a dropdown list in it, when selecting a date, I'll change the UI based on the data from database.

I can put all relevant data into request after signing in, and use JSTL in Main.jsp, but if the data is huge, this doesn't sound like a good idea, right?

Back to the old age when there's no JSTL or AJAX, how does jsp developer deal with this? And what is the best practice nowadays?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking to render about without JSTL or AJAX, the only option i see is to submit/send the form to server and get it back with updated view, but yes it will cost a lot in terms of performance.

I think for your use case:

1) you can get the data from server via AJAX on every update,

2) or, if the data is not customer dependent and is fixed in terms of UI, you can load it lazily in background, and change the view immediately on the user action.